# What are the security issues involved in compiled source codes (C++, Java, etc) when running on the machine?

Tags: java, c++, security, compilation

I was just wondering if compiled forms of source code actually have security problems?

I was thinking that since the source codes are already compiled in to machine code, then there shouldn't be any kind of security problem when the machine is already executing the instructions (i.e. compiled source code).

I haven't found any good and relevant explanation online.

Comment: There's some literature out there about code security. A collegue of mine had something on his desk, but I don't remember anymore. Googling for "software code security" yields some promising results though.

Comment: This question is not the best fit for this site, I think. But to have something: how can you **verify**, that the compiled code actually does what you think it should do? How can you verify that the compiler wasn't adding something to it, for example a keylogger code? Also, by executing the instructions, you also have the data in memory. Everything in there might be visible to someone you don't expect (though it might not be trivially easy to do that).

Comment: If you have a verifiable system (like .NET) you can preclude a number of attack vectors, like buffer overruns. This does not prevent an application from storing a password in plaintext in memory, though. An application does not magically become 100% safe. None of this is related to whether code is compiled or not.

Comment: You mean like the code that gets security updates from Microsoft every so often? Probably totally safe, and MS are just pretending that there are security problems because of the money they make from them.

Comment: @molbdnilo You are correct with one statement: Security is a process, not a product. If you care to educate yourself what verifiably safe really means read [Type Safety and Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbzz1a9a.aspx) and [Writing Verifiably Type-Safe Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01k04eaf.aspx). [Importance of Managed and Typesafe code](http://www.vistadb.net/technical/managed-code-review.aspx) may also turn out to be illuminating.

Comment: Security of what against what? HTTPS provides a kind of security that doesn't care about compiled code versus scripts, but that's because HTTPS secures communication against man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: See the famous paper by Ken Thompson: http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/ken/trust.html

Comment: So, uh, guys, this question is on hold. is there a StackExchange branch for security stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Of course they have security problems.

Examples:

1. Imagine a simple C/C++ code which is reading characters from standard input into char buffer and a programmer is not checking the length of the input. Such code is vulnerable to [Buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).
2. [Reverse engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering). Having machine code we can obtain more readable code of higher level with [decompiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler). With enough time you can find hard-coded keys or some secret algorithm, for example a method of encryption which is used for example in a game when sending highscores.
3. Tampering variables in the memory during the run-time. For example you have a game with score 100, so you are looking for this 100 in the memory assigned to executed process, let's say you've found 4 addresses with such value. Later you get 10 points more, so you have 110. So, you're checking this 4 addresses - which one of them contains now 110. If finally you found 1 address - bingo. Now you can override it with whatever you like, for example 999999.

Comment: Nice examples. That's something I used to do in my youth...

Comment: I don't understand your second example. Compiled code is usually a lot harder to reverse engineer than intermediate (Java Bytecode, CIL) or source code (in scripting environments like Lua).

Comment: @IInspectable You're absolutely right, it is harder. But the question is, what are the security issues with compiled code. And reverse engineering certainly *is* a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

One the the main security issues with compiled code is that you don't know what it does-  you can't easily inspect it. This makes it essential that you only ever run compiled code (software) from a trusted sources...

For example, I might write you a guess my number game, which you might love, but who's to say that while you're busy guessing numbers I haven't started a new thread of execution which is busy copying all the data on your machine?

There are also issues such as buffer overruns, SQL injection, Peek 'n' Poke etc that could still be there.

Compilation isn't done for security, but rather for efficiency. If you came to this expecting security, you might want to research obfuscation, but that's a whole other can of worms...